# What response "process_response()" produces when "or response" is returned?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

I've created a script using scrapy to parse the content from a website. The script is doing fine. However, I want that spider to retry when the url being used in the spider gets redirected (leading to some captcha page) and which is why I created a retry middleware.

I tried to understand why this portion `or response` is in place within `process_response()` in this line `return self._retry(request, reason, spider) or response` as I want this very method to retry, not to return response within that block.

This is my current approach:

```
def _retry(self, request, spider):
    check_url = request.url
    r = request.copy()
    r.dont_filter = True
    return r

def process_response(self, request, response, spider):
    if ("some_redirected_url" in response.url) and (response.status in RETRY_HTTP_CODES):
        return self._retry(request, spider) or response
    return response
```

Comment: You can use `request.replace` to create a new request with the original URL, which you can pass to `_retry`. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Your question isn't super clear. It looks like you've copied this from the default `RetryMiddleware` in `scrapy` (I'm not sure what you want to add to that). In that there is a maximum number of retries to be made and if that is reached it will just return the `response` (which has presumably failed). So that is what the `self.retry(...) or response` part means

Comment: My question might not be clear but it seems you answered it in the right way. I forgot that there is a limit of retries even when I do not explicitly define it. So, this portion `or response` comes into play when maximum number of retires reach it's limit, right? I would be glad to accept your answer if you post one. However, I've edited my post to make it clearer. Thanks @tomjn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case `return x or y` is a nice little short cut for

```py
if x:
    return x
else:
    return y
```

In the standard [`RetryMiddleware`](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html?highlight=retrymid#module-scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry) the `_retry` method has two branches

```py
if retries <= retry_times:
    ...
    return retryreq
else:
    ...
```

The `else` branch doesn't return anything, and if the method reaches the end without returning then `None` is returned implicitly. This means that the

```py
return self._retry(request, reason, spider) or response
```

line evaluates to

```
return None or response
```

and as `bool(None)` is `False`, `response` will be returned in this case. If on the other hand the `retry_times` hasn't been exceeded, `_retry` will return `retryreq` which will evaluate `True` and that will be returned from `process_response` instead.

In your code `_retry` always returns a `Response` and so the `or response` part will never be reached.

Comment: One last question on this: when `_retry` will return `retryreq` which will evaluate `True`, how come it will be returned from `process_response`? To be clearer, whenever this line `return True or response` is executed, the last `return` (situated at the very bottom) should not be reached.

Comment: It being evaluated as `True` means that it is returned. It is not `return True or response` it is `return retryreq or response`

Answer (score 1):

@tomjn had your Middleware's question covered but, as an alternative approach to retrying on those `302`s responses, you simply could tell Scrapy to stop redirecting `302`s and also add them to the list of codes that triggers the `RetryMiddleware`. Eg:

```
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings
RETRY_HTTP_CODES = get_project_settings().get("RETRY_HTTP_CODES", [])

class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
    # ...
    # do no redirect on this one
    handle_httpstatus_list = [302]
    # Add "302" to the retry codes list
    custom_settings = {"RETRY_HTTP_CODES": RETRY_HTTP_CODES + [302]}
```

Thus you wouldn't need to have a custom middleware for that.

Comment: Thanks for your alternative solution @Thiago Curvelo. I'm aware of this though. The thing is, my question was meant to get the clarity on the logic applied here `return self._retry(request, reason, spider) or response`.